# Run Gradle with verbose class loading?

Tags: java, classloader, gradle

My build script is encountering an error (below). Is there a way to run Gradle with the same type of output as invoking Java with `-verbose:class`?

The error in question, should anyone have some input:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':Project:compile'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.wrapException(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:49)
    ... more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraints violated when linking org/apache/ivy/core/module/descriptor/DependencyDescriptor class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the following environment variable, I believe...

```
GRADLE_OPTS="$GRADLE_OPTS -verbose:class"
```

and then invoke `gradle`.  Read this [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/first-look-building-java).

> Once Gradle is downloaded and unzipped, the environment variable
>   GRADLE_HOME can be set to the directory of the unzipped Gradle
>   installation and the PATH should be set to $GRADLE_HOME/bin or
>   %GRADLE_HOME%\bin. The Gradle installation page tells us that JVM
>   options used by Gradle can be set via either GRADLE_OPTS or JAVA_OPTS.
>   The Grade installation and configuration in the path can be confirmed
>   by running gradle -v at the command line once the environment variable
>   settings are sourced.

Comment: Thank you! I'm guessing it's not possible to configure this in a project file, like gradle.properties, for example?

Comment: Link is broken, perhaps:  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Answer (score 2):

Please add to your build.gradle task: jvmArgs '-verbose:class'.  For example to run gradle test, I use:

```
test{
    jvmArgs '-verbose:class'
}
```